# Security of ECC over finite fields of characteristic $p\approx2^{50\pm10}$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

What's the security of Elliptic Curve Cryptography over finite fields of word-sized characteristic $p\approx2^{50\pm10}$? We are talking about $\Bbb F_q$ where $q=p^k$ for some suitable $k$.

Furthermore, I would like to know about the possibility of pairings over fields of such word-sized characteristics.

References appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [recent paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/009.pdf) which proposes a curve with over the field $\mathbf F_q$ with $q=9767^{19}$. Section 2.2 talks a little about the extension degree.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! However, would you happen to have any reference for characteristic closer to the values I mentioned? Furthermore, I would like some references on pairings over fields of word-sized characteristics too.