# Diffie-Hellman with Galois field

Tags: diffie-hellman, finite-field

I Google around and can't find any page mentioning Diffie-Hellman with Galois field $GF(p^n)$ with $n>1$.

- Is there a reason for this?
- For example, wouldn't Diffie-Hellman with $GF(2^n)$ be desirable for computation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The security of the Diffie-Hellman protocol relies on the [Decisional Diffie-Hellman assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption), which is a stronger assumption than the [Discrete-Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) (DLP). In an earlier line of works, heuristic quasi-polynomial algorithms were shown for fields with small characterstic [J,BGJT,GKZ]. A proof (for expected run-time) was recently given by Wesolowski and Kleinjung [WK]. In particular, it was shown that DLP in $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}^\times$ can be solved in (expected) time $(pn)^{O(\log{n})}$. In light of these attacks, the Diffie-Hellman protocol should be avoided in fields of small characteristic.

[J] Joux, [A new index calculus algorithm with complexity L(1/4+o(1)) in very small characteristic](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/095)

[BGJT] Barbulescu et al., [A Heuristic Quasi-Polynomial Algorithm for Discrete Logarithm in Finite Fields of Small Characteristic](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/400)

[GKZ] Granger, Kleinjung and Zumbrägel, [On the discrete logarithm problem infinite fields of fixed characteristic](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/685.pdf)

[WK] Wesolowski and Kleinjung [Discrete logarithms in quasi-polynomial time in finite fields of fixed characteristic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10668)

Comment: Are there any threshold for the size of the characteristics?

Comment: @kelalaka: we recently had a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77742/555) touching that, the link in comment is an interesting article by our favorite bear.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I had always assumed that DH was done in $GF(2^m)$, partly because squaring is easy and makes it easy to exponentiate.